# change font color based on file_get_html result

Tags: php, fonts, colors

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<font color="#66FF33">
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
echo file_get_html('http://website-A')->plaintext;
echo file_get_html('website-B')->plaintext;
?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

The plaintext output returned from website-A is always going to be one of the following:

1. Washington
2. Lincoln

How can I change my code so that when website-A returns Washington then the font color of the plaintext echo for A & B is green, and when website-A returns Lincoln then the font color of the plaintext echo for A & B changes to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<html>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$file_A = file_get_html('http://website-A')->plaintext;
if ($file_A == 'Washington') {
    $fontcolor = 'green';
} else {
    $fontcolor = 'red';
} ?>
<font color="<?php echo $fontcolor; ?>">
<?php
echo $file_A;
echo file_get_html('website-B')->plaintext;
?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Working!